# Place to keep a list of trusted external IP addresses on a system?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, security, ip

### What I have

Many services on my system trust the same list of IP addresses.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151491/example-com-is-ok-for-domain-example-what-is-example-ip-address), I mention/use/refer to:

- `192.0.2.43`,
- `198.51.100.2` and
- `203.0.113.76`

when configuring:

- `iptables`,
- `fail2ban`,
- `nginx`,
- `mysql-server` etc.

### What I do

Right now I manually configure each service to allow access from every IP

### What I want

Keep a maintainable list of my trusted IP addresses in a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) place somewhere on the system.

1. Every time I need to add/remove an IP, I make changes in that place only.
2. The changes are picked up by a shell script I will have to write, and are reflected further in each of the corresponding service configurations.

I hope to reuse an existing, ideally elegant and self-explanatory approach as much as possible, before I revert to creating some custom newline delimited text file in `/etc`.

### What I consider

- I'm already restricting SSH with `iptables`, allowing my trusted IPs. Reading the IPs from `iptables` rules could be a way to do it, but it's messy.
- Add the following to `/etc/hosts`:

  ```
    192.0.2.43 localtrust
    198.51.100.2 localtrust
    203.0.113.76 localtrust
  ```

  Then use `getent` to [get the IPs](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first):

  ```
    # getent ahosts localtrust | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq
    192.0.2.43
    198.51.100.2
    203.0.113.76
  ```

  and `for … in` through that list easily.
- Store the IPs newline delimited in `/etc/hosts.allow`, one IP per line. Each time I need them, `cat /etc/hosts.allow` and `for … in`.
- The [`hosts.allow` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow) mentions the `@netgroup` concept, and from [its manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netgroup) it sounds what I'm looking for:

  > The netgroup file defines "netgroups", which are sets of (host, user, domain) tuples, used for permission checking when doing remote mounts, remote logins and remote shells.

  Except I don't have `/etc/netgroup` on my system and when I search for it on the internet, the results I get are old or irrelevant. Is this a deprecated concept?
- Store the IPs newline delimited in a custom file I'll have to introduce into the system. Then `cat` it and `for … in`

Anything else? What would you do?

Hope this is not considered opinion-based, because I'm asking for industry standard/best practices.

If there are none and/or my question is exotic, then dumping the IPs into `/etc/hosts.allow` is the cleanest approach, because I can see how the `/etc/hosts` may get overwritten on boot on some systems/OS templates, effectively clearing my trusted IPs list and locking me out of the system. I have never used `/etc/hosts.allow` or seen it in action, so my experience is limited. Am I going to regret messing with it?

Comment: Why do you have to configure all these services on their own? Configuring the firewall should be enough to limit access, as it's the "perimeter"

Comment: @Panki hi, good question. For situations when I need to configure an individual service to exclude admins from specific rules, and firewall won't help (it only allows or rejects a connection on a given port). For example, Nginx applies [`limit_req`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) to all except admins. Fail2Ban monitors a honeypot and bans all except admins. Admins are determined by their connecting IP address.